# GPUImage overlay live video with corner detection

Tags: iphone, ios, gpuimage

Trying to get a basic filter working with GPUImage, but not sure how to properly set it up to display the crosshairs over the live video feed, when detecting corners. I tried adding the crosshairs to the blend filter, along with the video, then add that to the gpuimageview, but all I get is a white screen. Any ideas?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.



    videoCamera = [[GPUImageVideoCamera alloc] initWithSessionPreset:AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480 cameraPosition:AVCaptureDevicePositionBack];
    videoCamera.outputImageOrientation = UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;


    GPUImageView *filteredVideoView = (GPUImageView *)self.view;


    GPUImageCrosshairGenerator *crosshairGenerator = [[GPUImageCrosshairGenerator alloc] init];
    crosshairGenerator.crosshairWidth = 15.0;
    [crosshairGenerator forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];


    customFilter = [[GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter alloc] init];
    [customFilter setCornersDetectedBlock:^(GLfloat* cornerArray, NSUInteger cornersDetected, CMTime frameTime){
        [crosshairGenerator renderCrosshairsFromArray:cornerArray count:cornersDetected frameTime:frameTime];
        NSLog(@"corners: %u", cornersDetected);
    }];


    GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter *blendFilter = [[GPUImageAlphaBlendFilter alloc] init];
    [blendFilter forceProcessingAtSize:CGSizeMake(480.0, 640.0)];

    [videoCamera addTarget:blendFilter];
    [crosshairGenerator addTarget:blendFilter];
    [blendFilter addTarget:filteredVideoView];


    [videoCamera startCameraCapture];

}
```

Comment: why not add the cross-hairs outside of the GPUImageView? Just as an overlay using another view?

Comment: I mean setup a CAShapeLayer on top of the GPUImageView in your ViewController's view and draw the cross-hair on that. Unless I'm missing something else you are trying to achieve, this is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I may be missing it, but when do you add `customFilter` as a target of `videoCamera`? As it stands, it doesn't look like you're feeding frames into the corner detector.

Comment: @BradLarson Looks like that was it. Wasn't sure how to properly add everything

Answer (score 0):

This is how ur code should be in **Swift 2.0**

```
var liveCam:GPUImageVideoCamera!
var edgesDetector:GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter!
var crosshairGenerator:GPUImageCrosshairGenerator!
@IBOutlet weak var camView: GPUImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    liveCam = GPUImageVideoCamera(sessionPreset: AVCaptureSessionPreset640x480, cameraPosition: .Back)
    liveCam.outputImageOrientation = .Portrait

    crosshairGenerator = GPUImageCrosshairGenerator()
    crosshairGenerator.crosshairWidth = 15
    crosshairGenerator.forceProcessingAtSize(CGSize(width: 480, height: 640))


    edgesDetector = GPUImageHarrisCornerDetectionFilter()
    edgesDetector.blurRadiusInPixels = 2 //Default value
    edgesDetector.threshold = 0.2 //Default value

    edgesDetector.cornersDetectedBlock = {(cornerArray:UnsafeMutablePointer<GLfloat>,cornersDetected:UInt,frameTime:CMTime) -> Void in
        self.crosshairGenerator.renderCrosshairsFromArray(cornerArray, count: cornersDetected, frameTime: frameTime)
        print("\(cornerArray) =-= \(cornersDetected) =-= \(frameTime)")

    }


    liveCam.addTarget(edgesDetector)
    edgesDetector.addTarget(crosshairGenerator)
    crosshairGenerator.addTarget(camView)

    liveCam.startCameraCapture()
}
```

The result :

[image]